# R equivalent to Stata's bysort x y (z):

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, stata, tidyverse

In Stata, one can run a command within groups and sorted by `x` and `y`, and further sorted by `z` (but not using `z` in the grouping) by doing the following:

```
bysort x y (z): command
```

How can one do this in **R**, particularly the sorting part?

Note that the sorting by `x`, `y`, and `z` is important.

Here is what I think is likely part of the code, using the `tidyverse`:

```
data %>% group_by(x,y) %>% command
```

Example data:

```
a <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), y=c(3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6), z=c(8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1), val=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

Within each `x`, `y` group, I want to do the following:

```
mutate(lag = lag(val))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arrange` function in dplyr. use `desc` within that if you don't want ascending. Also the use of `group_by` is unnecessary for this purpose - the order in which you specify the columns is the priority in which rows will be ordered by..

```
data %>%
  arrange(x, y, desc(z))
```

Update:
I think you already know how to do this part now that I’ve showed you how to sort...

```
data %>%
  arrange(x, y, desc(z)) %>%
  group_by(x,y) %>%
  mutate(lagged = lag(z))
```

Comment: Arrange will help but group by x and y is needed indeed. The parenthesis in stata's bysort makes sure that the data is sorted by z, but z won't be included in the grouping.

Comment: What is group_by needed for exactly? Not for the sorting question posed by OP. It may be needed only if he needs to do other things within groups

Comment: He needs to generate a lag per group. It makes a difference if you use group_by

Comment: I saw he already had code for that. I was only addressing the sorting

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that R does not have a single equivalent to `Stata` `sortby`.  It depends on the  `command` following `sortby`. Unlike Stata, R does not require sorting for subgroup analysis in most situations.
In this case, we do not need to sort by `x` and `y`. I am not sure your expected outcome, but one option could be something like this:

```
a %>% 
  group_by(x, y) %>% 
  arrange(z) %>% 
  mutate(lag = lag(val)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
      x     y     z   val   lag
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     6     1     8    NA
2     2     6     2     7     8
3     2     5     3     6    NA
4     2     5     4     5     6
5     1     4     5     4    NA
6     1     4     6     3     4
7     1     3     7     2    NA
8     1     3     8     1     2
```

Comment: This does not sort by x and y as requested

Comment: The question as I understood it was how to sort on all of x,y,z. The op already showed correct code for calculating lags within groups...

Answer (score 1):

For your specific question with your (updated?) data and `mutate()` command, it seems like you're already on the right track with `group_by()`, `arrange()`, and `mutate()`.

But for the broader question, there are some split-apply problems that are not quite as straightforward as perhaps they'd be in Stata. Here's an example of summarizing groups, which has a more explicit split-apply form.

```r
library(tidyverse)
a <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), y = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6), z = c(8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1), val = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
a %>%
  group_split(x, y) %>%
  purrr::map(summary)
#> [[1]]
#>        x           y           z             val      
#>  Min.   :1   Min.   :3   Min.   :7.00   Min.   :1.00  
#>  1st Qu.:1   1st Qu.:3   1st Qu.:7.25   1st Qu.:1.25  
#>  Median :1   Median :3   Median :7.50   Median :1.50  
#>  Mean   :1   Mean   :3   Mean   :7.50   Mean   :1.50  
#>  3rd Qu.:1   3rd Qu.:3   3rd Qu.:7.75   3rd Qu.:1.75  
#>  Max.   :1   Max.   :3   Max.   :8.00   Max.   :2.00  
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>        x           y           z             val      
#>  Min.   :1   Min.   :4   Min.   :5.00   Min.   :3.00  
#>  1st Qu.:1   1st Qu.:4   1st Qu.:5.25   1st Qu.:3.25  
#>  Median :1   Median :4   Median :5.50   Median :3.50  
#>  Mean   :1   Mean   :4   Mean   :5.50   Mean   :3.50  
#>  3rd Qu.:1   3rd Qu.:4   3rd Qu.:5.75   3rd Qu.:3.75  
#>  Max.   :1   Max.   :4   Max.   :6.00   Max.   :4.00  
#> 
[...detail omitted...]
```